# Different number of grid cells between years when using a grid layer to look at area of land cover change over time

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-grid

My goal is to calculate the area of mangrove cover (vector layer) per grid cell (vector layer) over time (yearly), to determine land cover change.

[image: grid and polygon layers]

I have tried two ways so far.
Initially I wanted to Intersect the grid and polygon layers then dissolve by ID and then calculate the area. This has two problems 1) it does not include any grid cells with 0 mangrove polygon intercept, and 2) there are duplicated grid ID values where two polygons intercept the same grid.

[image: grid ID]

I also tried Union. This includes the grid cells with 0 mangrove polygon, but still has the issue with duplication.

[image: grid splitting?]

[image: excel spreadsheet]

Any ideas on how I can avoid this duplication so that I have the same number of grid cells per year so that I can compare between years?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with in the end is as follows.

I Intercepted the grid and mangrove polygon layers, calculated the area and joined the attributes table with the grid attributes table by ID. Then I cleaned the dataset as necessary.